# How to increment a primary key in an insert statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write an `insert` statement into a table the columns looks like this

- `demandtypeid` (`PK, FK, int, not null`)
- `characvalueid` (`PK, FK, int, not null`)
- `percentage` (`int null`)
- `lastuser` (`varchar(100), null`)
- `lastedited` (`datetime, null`)

Here is the `INSERT` statement. Notice the there is not values at the

```
value( ,  , 'Bob')
```

as I think that's where the auto-increment command should go

```
insert into tr_demandtypecharac(demandtypeID, characvalueid, lastuser) 
values(  , , 'Bob')
```

Please help with a simple little statement

I just want to know how to manually insert into this table

Here's my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tr_demandtypecharac](
[demandtypeid] [int] NOT NULL,
[characvalueid] [int] NOT NULL,
[percentage] [int] NULL,
[lastuser] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[lastedited] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tr_dtc_pkey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[demandtypeid] ASC,
[characvalueid] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tr_demandtypecharac]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tr_dtc_cvid] 
FOREIGN KEY([characvalueid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tr_characvalue] ([characvalueid])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tr_demandtypecharac]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tr_dtc_dtid] 
FOREIGN KEY([demandtypeid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tr_demandtype] ([demandtypeid])
```

Comment: Your question says `I just want to know how to manually insert into this table` but your other comments indicate that you do not have an autoincremented column and that you cannot change the schema. The short answer is that, without changing the schema to include an autoincremented column, you cannot get autoincremented values. There are weird hacks you could use, like storing global variables in a table somewhere, but that's a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `CREATE TABLE` statement you posted, without auto-increment (aka identity) columns, you would insert providing all columns and values, like this:

```
insert into tr_demandtypecharac(
       demandtypeid, characvalueid, 
       percentage, lastuser, lastedited) 
values(2, 3, 80, 'Bob', '01/01/2012')
```

If, however, you do make them auto-increment by changing the `CREATE TABLE` to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tr_demandtypecharac](
[demandtypeid] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[characvalueid] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[percentage] [int] NULL,
[lastuser] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[lastedited] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tr_dtc_pkey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[demandtypeid] ASC,
[characvalueid] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
 )
```

Then you would insert providing all non-identity (non-autoincrement) columns like this:

```
insert into tr_demandtypecharac(
      percentage, lastuser, 
      lastedited) 
values(80, 'Bob', '01/01/2012')
```

**However, it is not common to have more than one column as an identity (autoincrement) column, and generally, this column is the only PRIMARY KEY column.**

Answer (score 5):

If you want an int column that is unique and autoincrementing, use the [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),
 fname varchar (20),
 minit char(1),
 lname varchar(30)
)
```

Then when you insert into the table, do not insert anything for that column -- it will autoincrement itself.

Answer (score 0):

If a column is an autoincement column (which is different than a primary key column) then you omit the column in your insert statement and it will be filled in.

```
INSERT INTO tr_demandtypecharac (lastuser) VALUES ('Bob')
```

Comment: Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'demandtypeid', table 'a7itm.dbo.tr_demandtypecharac'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Both the demandtypeid and characvalueid are set to Identity Increment = 0 : Allow Nulls : false

Comment: Please post your table Create To --> script

Comment: I didn't create the DB nor do I have permission to change the data

Comment: No problems.  You right-click on the table.  Select create to query window or file.  I just want to check your table definition.  If you could edit your question to include it that would be wonderful

Comment: I Posted the Decription in the main post, thanks I humbly appreciate it

Comment: There is currently no records in the file.  I just want to know how to INSERT values

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and needed to update a purchased database with a set of records.  My solution was to find the highest key used so far, then use that as the base of my insert.  The core of it was ROWNUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PART_CODE).

The key is the "recnum" field in the inadjinf table.  I determined that the highest current key was 675400 and updated my query to be:

```
insert into inadjinf (recnum, user_id, adj_type, adj_status, trans_date, part_code, lotqty, uom, cost_ctr, lot, location, to_cost_ctr, to_location, rec_status, to_part_grade, to_rec_status, remarks1, uom_conv) 
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY INVDET.PART_CODE) + 675400 as recnum, 'CHRSTR' as user_id, 'M' as adj_type, 'O' as adj_status, '2020-10-23' as trans_date, invdet.part_code, sum(lotqty) as lotqty, uom, 
cost_ctr, lot, location, 'NS' as to_cost_ctr, '500A' as to_location, rec_status, 'Q' as to_part_grade, 'H' as to_rec_status, 'NS Scrap Request from MSobers 10/21/2020' as remarks1, '1' as uom_conv
from invdet
inner join partmstr on invdet.part_code = partmstr.part_code
where 
invdet.part_code In
(
'86038',
'1271',
'VM-0021',
'CO-0107',
...
'FO-0391',
'FO-0376'
)
and lot not in (select lot from inadjinf where trans_date = '2020-10-23' and user_id = 'CHRSTR')
group by invdet.part_code, uom, cost_ctr, lot, location, rec_status
```

My output started with 675401 and went up from there.  In the end, I updated the system's internal "next id field" table record.

Answer (score -7):

You should not use int as primary keys... heres a article about it: http://techtrainedmonkey.com/2012/07/30/why-integers-are-lousy-primary-keys/

but if you do... set the field as identity and Sql Server will do it for you... check it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: -1 - Integers are a good choice for primary keys, unless you have a very good reason against them. But you do need a very good reason.

Comment: I agree with Oded. That article is short, poorly written, no details given, and draws an unfair conclusion. Why does his poor design mean that ints don't make good primary keys? I could go on and on.

Comment: im sorry... i desagree... this is the kind of "concept" we should get rid of... ints are a good key for minor systems, but for real world (scalable, multi-tenant, havy-use, etc...) apps, they will get you in more trouble than solve... i dont mean to sound condescendant... but im facing problems with int keys right now...

Comment: The guy in the article would have had the same problem even if he used random integers instead of guids for keys. He still has to check whether or not the ids of one database will conflict with the ids of another database, regardless of the likelihood of there being conflicts.

Comment: Most real world applications **most** do not need that kind of scalability, are not multi tenant or have that kind of usage. If you need such an application **then** you have good reason to not use integer keys.